# Debug dll and doesn't contain the architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, delphi, debugging, dll, clion

I build a 64-bit dll in Clion. Tollchain Visual Studio

[image: Clion toolchain settings]

The project compiles successfully. For debugging I use Win64 host application compiled in Delphi. I added this application in the configuration editor and when I start debugging I get the message

> 'Project.exe' doesn't contain the architecture x86_64
> Process finished with exit code 0

The application itself without a debugger (or from under the Visual Studio debugger) starts and loads my dll.

---

Additional info

I have compiled an empty Delphi project

```pascal
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

begin
end.
```

When I run it from under the debugger as a host application, I get the same error.

When running an empty project built in Visual Studio as an host application

```c
int main()
{
}
```

the debugger starts without errors

Platform: Win64

For comparison PE Headers Delphi and VC programs

Delphi

[image]

[image]

Visual Studio

[image]

[image]

Comment: Different Debuggers use different style of Debug information that is included in executable. This means that no every debugger can successfully debug any file. So I'm guessing that Visual Studio isn't recognizing Delphi Debug information as valid to use. You may get around this by forcing Delphi to output Debug information into separate .TDS file which will be created along side your executable or DLL. Visual studio might then be able to use Debug information from that file in order to successfully create a Debug session.

Comment: @SilverWarior I don't need Debug Information from exe. I debugging dll. And Visual Studio perfectly allows you to debug dll, which is called by the host process compiled in Delphi. Yes, without debug information from the exe, but it is not needed either. The problem is that I cannot start this host process in Clion. I am currently working in two IDEs. I write code in Сlion, and debugging in MSVС

Comment: Same ways as executables needs to contain Debug information so does DLL's.

Comment: @SilverWarior What for? The Visual Studio does not require this. I have not come across a debugger that would require debug information for modules other than the one being debugged. If it is, that's good, but it's optional.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Clion tests for the [Machine Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#machine-types) flag in the [COFF File Header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#coff-file-header-object-and-image). Unfortunately, I don't know of any built-in way in Delphi to set this value.

The best option would therefore be to create a tiny Delphi program that can set this value to the correct value

```
CONST IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 = $8664;
```

that you then execute as a post-build event.

Comment: Delphi sets this flag

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas - OP needs to figure out what - _precisely_ - it is that Clion doesn't like...

Comment: [PE Header Delphi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3aEt.png)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov: OP = Original Poster (a.k.a. Post Author) - in this case, You :-)

Comment: If Delphi didn't set this then its 64 bit compiler would be useless, wouldn't it?